# PHP / JavaScript: How to pass variable from one page to another

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, variables, get

I am new to PHP and hope someone can help me with this.

I have a page (`index.php`) where users can select a language. 
If no language is selected than the page URL is just index.php which defaults to English. 
If they select a language than the page gets reload and the variable `?lang=xy` is added to the URL which defines the page language. 
E.g. for German the page URL would then be `index.php?lang=de` .

So far everything works as intended.

Now I have a navbar on the index page that allows to navigate to other pages which are all saved as separate php files (like `page1.php, page2.php, page3.php` etc.).

**How can I manage** that if someone has selected a language on the index page and then navigates to another page **that the language variable is passed along to all other pages** ?
E.g. for German the other pages shoud be `page1.php?lang=de, page2.php?lang=de, page3.php?lang=de` etc.

I know I can use `$_GET["lang"]` on each page to fetch the variable but couldn't find a way to pass this on from the index page to other pages using PHP or JavaScript/jQuery, ideally in a way that I can set this more general instead of separately for every single link.

**Note:**
I am using undordered lists with standard links to create my navbar, e.g.:

```
<li><a href="page1.php">Page1</a></li>
```

Can someone help me with this ?

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: You can use php sessions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use cookies to do so

```
setcookie(name, value, expire, path, domain, secure, httponly);
```

i.e.:

```
setcookie('language', 'german', 60000,"/");
```

and then check this wherever with

```
$_COOKIE["language"]
```

http://php.net/manual/en/features.cookies.php reference

Comment: Thanks a lot - this is perfect ! Can you explain what the part after 'german' does here ?

Comment: That's how long the cookie persists for before it expires and you'll need to create another one (in seconds), 60*60*24 will last a day, for example.

Comment: Thanks again, Jack ! Got it. And what does the "/" ?

Comment: That's just the path of where it's stored, for the most part keep it as "/".

Answer (score 0):

you can use sessions to pass variables to any page,it's more secure than cookies as it's a server side,

example:

After Posting Data:

```
<?php
    session_start();
        if(isset($_POST)){
        $var_name=$this->db->real_escape_string($_POST['input_name']);
        $_SESSION['var1_sess']=true;
        $_SESSION['var1_sess']=$var_name;
        }
?>
```

**note**:session_start() must be in the first line of the file.

Comment: Security isn't really an issue here though, just storing a language.

Answer (score -1):

If you are using  to select languages, just add onchange event to  then submit the form to index.php

```
<form action="index.php">
    <select name="lang" onchange="javascript:this.form.submit()">
        <option value="en">English</option>
        <option value="xy">XY</option>
    </select>
</form>
```

and in the same page

```
<?php  
$lang = $_GET['lang'];
if(empty($lang)){
    $lang = "en";
}
?>
```

Then pass the $lang to where you want to

```
<li><a href="page1.php?<?php echo $lang; ?>">Page1</a></li>
```